# mvc asp.net setting the application name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

In my web.config file I have this

```
<add key="ApplicationName" value="Costing" />
```

I dont have any AspNetSqlMembershipProvider

whenever I get an error, I get this message

> Server Error in '/' Application.

how do I actually set the name of my application to something other than '/' ?

Comment: this was  not added to my text for some reason   <add key="ApplicationName" value="Costing" />

Comment: why dont you use AspNetSqlMembershipProvider